# How to enable command Response.Write in C# (as referencing class for webapp ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.write

I want to make procedure like this code below:

```
void accessBySession(String user, String webqname)
{
  ...
  Response.Write("<script>alert('You can't access this page !');document.location='dashboard.aspx'; </script>  ");
}
```

I've added `using System.Web;` but still there is an error in command response (The name 'Response' does not exist in current context).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the full namespace:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('You can't access this page !');document.location='dashboard.aspx'; </script>)
```

Comment: @Ana Glad to be of help!